# unable to access @handles on twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using the following function to access tweets from an account on twitter.  When I enter cs50 it works fine but when I enter any handle like @cs50 it returns none.

```
def get_user_timeline(screen_name, count=200):
"""Return list of most recent tweets posted by screen_name."""

# ensure count is valid
if count < 1 or count > 200:
    raise RuntimeError("invalid count")

# ensure environment variables are set
if not os.environ.get("API_KEY"):
    raise RuntimeError("API_KEY not set")
if not os.environ.get("API_SECRET"):
    raise RuntimeError("API_SECRET not set")

# get screen_name's most recent tweets
# https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup
# https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline
# https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/endpoints.py
try:
    twitter = Twython(os.environ.get("API_KEY"), os.environ.get("API_SECRET"))
    user = twitter.lookup_user(screen_name=screen_name)
    if user[0]["protected"]:
        return None
    tweets = twitter.get_user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=count)
    return [html.unescape(tweet["text"].replace("\n", " ")) for tweet in tweets]
except TwythonAuthError:
    raise RuntimeError("invalid API_KEY and/or API_SECRET") from None
except TwythonRateLimitError:
    raise RuntimeError("you've hit a rate limit") from None
except TwythonError:
    return None
```

Comment: Please add the relevant `import` (s) to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `@` sign is a problem for the API, you can clean the variable before passing it in like this:

```
screen_name = screen_name[1:] if screen_name.startswith("@") else screen_name
```

Comment: no, that's not the problem. the address cs50 and @cs50 both exist but I'm only able to get the former.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Twitter don't allow usernames to start with an '@' character, or am I wrong about that?